# uint8_t pointer address increases by 4 instead of 1

Tags: c, pointers, byte

I just started coding again and got a problem, which I am not able to solve.

I have a list, where each element has one byte. Then I want to access the content byte for byte by the address. But the address keeps increasing by 4 bytes.

I know this issue, when the list is initialised as a 4-byte-type.

Any ideas how I can solve it?

Edit: Sorry my explanationwas a little bit wrong.

```c
int main() 
{   
    uint8_t* list;
    list = (uint8_t*)calloc(32, sizeof(uint8_t));
    printf("Address: %p\n", &list);
    printf("Address: %p\n", &list + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Address: 00DBF904
Address: 00DBF908
```

---

Edit:
Thanks for the answers. This is the solution to my problem:

```
int main() 
{   
    uint8_t* list;
    list = (uint8_t*)calloc(32, sizeof(uint8_t));
    printf("Address: %p\n", &list);
    printf("Address: %p\n", (uint8_t*)&list + 1);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `list` is a pointer to `uint8_t`, but `&list` is a pointer to pointer. And in your architecture, a pointer uses 4 bytes, hence the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is already a pointer (to `uint8_t`, size 1Byte), and `&list` points to that pointer (to pointer, size 4Bytes). Using pointer arithmetics adding one means adding the size of the data type pointed to. The addition should work as you expected when you change it to:

```
printf("Address: %p\n", list);
printf("Address: %p\n", list + 1);
```

If you really want to add 1 to the pointer value you can cast it to a `void*` before adding:

```
printf("Address: %p\n", &list);
printf("Address: %p\n", ((void*)&list) + 1);
```

Comment: Oh, i see. I actually wanted to get the pointer of the pointer.
But then I will choose another solution. Thanks

Comment: @unpwn I added that as well.

Comment: @jf_ I actually meant that because `printf` takes variadic arguments, the compiler won't cast it to `void*` for you. And with `%p` it expects a `void*`. This hardly ever matters, but there are systems where pointers to different types can be of different sizes. So you should always cast to `void*` when printing an address that way.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `list` is a pointer, and the `&list` is the pointer to the `list`, so if you want to increase the address, you can directly use `list+1`.

```
printf("Address: %p\n", list);
printf("Address: %p\n", list + 1);
```

And if you want to get the value, just use `*(list)` and then increase the address.

```
printf("Address: %d\n", *list);
printf("Address: %d\n", *(list+1));
```